# Flutter error while showing profile picture google play games

Tags: flutter, dart, google-play-games

Using the play_games extension, I'm having trouble returning the user's profile image.

Use the method below to login and set the state with the return of the user's data.

Image provider: NetworkImage ("content: //com.google.android.gms.games.background/images/f56551ac/42", scale: 1.0)

```
// Google Play Games stance
final GameServices gameservices = GameServices();
Account profile;
ui.Image profileimage;

void _login() async {
    final res = await gameservices.login();
    final resimage = await res.hiResImage;

    setState(() {
        profile = res;
        profileimage = resimage;
    });

    print(profileimage);
}
```

In the widget I'm in the form of NetworkImage, but it's still not rendering on the screen.

this error: The argument type 'Image' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'.

```
Container(
    width: 128,
    height: 128,
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
    child: CircleAvatar(
        backgroundImage: NetworkImage(this.profileimage != null ? this.profileimage : 'https://api.adorable.io/avatars/128/')
    ),
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.white,
        shape: BoxShape.circle
    ),

),
```

[image: image not rendering]

[  RESOLVED!!! ]

Change my code and play_games returns type vars.
Lets go:

```
Future<Uint8List> get hiResImage async =>
  await _fetchToMemory(await _channel.invokeMethod('getHiResImage'));

Future<Uint8List> get iconImage async =>
  await _fetchToMemory(await _channel.invokeMethod('getIconImage'));
}


Future<Uint8List> _fetchToMemory(Map<dynamic, dynamic> result) {
    Uint8List bytes = result['bytes'];
    if (bytes == null) {
        print('was null, mate');
        return Future.value(null);
    }
    // Completer<Image> completer = new Completer();
    // decodeImageFromList(bytes, (image) => completer.complete(image));
    return Future.value(bytes);
}
```

And my code, only this change:

```
Uint8List profileimage;
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Flutter is yelling at you because you gave it a URL with protocol `content://`, when it expects `http://` or `https://` for a `NetworkImage` widget. See documentation at: https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/images/network-image

Comment: Yes, how to convert this to image or http?s?

Answer (score 0):

This happen because google provide encoded image. In android we can use `ImageManager` for that as google suggest.

In flutter there are mechanism for getting `Future<Image>` from `hiresImageUri`. Check [here](https://github.com/flame-engine/play_games/blob/713dc3711432e540553945c0d21891fe8dc39f3c/lib/play_games.dart#L93).

Use Something like below,

```
profile.hiResImage.then((Image result){
        //here you can get image in result
});
```

Comment: This error: Compiler message:
lib/main.dart:77:32: Error: The argument type 'Null Function(Image/*1*/)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'FutureOr<dynamic> Function(Image/*2*/)'.
 - 'Image/*1*/' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/image.dart' ('/C:/ProgramData/Flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/image.dart').
 - 'FutureOr' is from 'dart:async'.
 - 'Image/*2*/' is from 'dart:ui'.
                this.profile.hiResImage.then((Image result) {